# Phalcon include relationships in json

Tags: phalcon

I've been having a look at phalcon as an alternative to a laravel project that I'm running. It's mainly a REST api. I'm trying to figure out how to include relationships in a json response for models.

For example, if I had 2 models, set up like below:

```
class Clients extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

  public function initialize() {
     $this->hasMany('clientid','Contacts','clientid')
  }

}

class Contacts extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {

  public function initialize() {
    $this->belongsTo('clientid','Clients','clientid')
  }
}
```

And I did a:

```
$clients = Client::find();
return json_encode($clients->toArray());
```

How would I get it to automatically include the contacts?

I need to output to be something like this:

```
 [{
   clientid:'1111',
   contacts:[
      {
      contactid:111
      }
   ]
 }];
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#taking-advantage-of-relationships):

> By accessing an attribute with the same name as the relationship will retrieve all its related record(s).

Based on the above, you should be able to access the contacts via the relationship defined like so:

```
$clients = Client::find();
$clientContacts = $clients->contacts;
// do something with the contacts
```

Edit:

Try to loop through your $contacts and then get the related record(s):

```
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    // Do something with the contacts...
    $contacts[$client->id] = $client->contacts;
}
```

Comment: that may work well for a single record, but it doesn't seem to work at all for resultset...give it a burl

Comment: Yes, you're right. How about if you iterate through your $clients and then use $client->contacts? See my edit.